# google map markers displays in IE but not in chrome or firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have a google map that pulls in addresses values from document and plots them. It works fine in IE ie. map displays fine and markers are showing up. In Chrome and Firefox however, only the map shows up but not the markers..I don't understand it.. Neither is infowindow working, since the markers are not showing. I didn't include the inforwindow code here though!

```
var geocoder;
var map;

function initializeMap() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(39.88445,-86.11084);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 9,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        myOptions);
}

function codeAddress() {
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({}); 
    $('span.LocationAddress').each(function(index) {
        var addy = $(this).text();          
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': addy}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map, 
                    position: results[0].geometry.location,
                    title:addy          
                });     
            } 

        });
    });
}
```

Comment: are you getting any errors in firebug? are you able to put up a link?

Comment: How do you check for errors in firebug?? the map displays fine. Its just not plotting the markerss..so something is going on in codeaddress() function..please help! :(

Comment: Try invert the order of attributes: first position, second map. This dont have many sense, but...

Comment: did you manage to fix your issue?

Answer (score 0):

if you add the firebug add on in firefox, press 12 once installed, it will show up an error if there are any code problems. Also, add:

```
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map, 
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                title:addy          
            });     
        } else{ console.log(google.maps.GeocoderStatus);}
```

this should show what the status is coming back as.